# Smooth Edges for transparent animation in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, psd

I'm currently building a game, using the citrus engine. Therefor I am importing my bitmap into the flash library as psd layers. The compiled swfs are loaded on runtime as game graphics.

I smoothed the edges in photoshop and for still pictures (like the standing hero) it works quite good, but my animations look ragged. My game has a zoom function and on screen resize the graphics look ragged, too.

What is the best way of getting my animation frames into flash (with nice smooth edges)? Would it be better, to export them from photoshop as a webcompatible format? Or can I improve flashs displaying of images somehow?

Comment: Where are your bitmaps? In the library or loaded at runtime?

Comment: In the library. For every animated game object there is an swf-file containing labeled stage animations. I guess it can be done on runtime, if necessary, as long as the labels are there, but I dont really know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 should improve the image quality:

Catchasbitmap= true  (Not mandatory takes memory but easy on cpu)

Smoothing = true   (is cpu consuming)

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?289874-AS3-bitmap-smoothing

Comment: Can I somehow make Catchasbitmap and Smoothing work inside my fla?

Comment: It is really better now (The ragged edges are not so obvious anymore), but my animations (imported the same way, smoothing turned on) still look a little bit worse than the rest. Is that normal?

Comment: You need to use bitmap animation technique instead of vector movieclip.   http://blog.flexwiz.net/spritesheet-animation-in-as3/